# React native android production mode

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have completed developing react native app in android studio as a new activity, it works fine on emulator as it utilizes localhost server. Now i want to run this app on my device, but it throws exception

```
E/unknown:React: IOException requesting status from packager java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8081) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
  at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:267)
  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:191)
  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:127)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:188)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:461)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:918)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform$Android.connectSocket(Platform.java:190)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:196)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:245)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:267)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:224)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:195)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.access$100(Call.java:34)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:162)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
  at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:252)
  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:191) 
  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:127) 
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:188) 
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:461) 
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:918) 
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform$Android.connectSocket(Platform.java:190) 
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:196) 
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172) 
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367) 
  at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128) 
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328) 
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:245) 
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:267) 
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:224) 
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:195) 
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.access$100(Call.java:34) 
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:162) 
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33) 
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I think it still trying to connect to my machine server. I tried switching off dev environment by:

```
"http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android?dev=false" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
```

but i get this error on my server

```
Error: Unrecognized platform: android?dev=false
at DependencyGraph._getRequestPlatform (index.js:169:13)
at index.js:137:23
```

Please suggest what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to generate a release apk to upload to the store? If so have you read through this? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content

Comment: @rmevans9 i just want to test it on my nexus before i go for release apk. When i open it on mobile it throws the above mentioned exception.

Comment: It sounds like you are not building the app in "release mode" which means it is looking for the dev server which it can't find. If you hit the back button while the red screen is up then hit the menu button does the dev menu still open? If so you likely need to either build in "release mode" or goto dev settings and set the server ip and port to your machine running the packager

Comment: @rmevans9 how can i make app in release mode? Any idea. I am using android studio.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it in Android Studio but the documentation walks you through doing it with Gradle. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content